how to fix internal server error next.js occasionally?
In my next.js project only in development mode (npm run dev), I encounter this error occasionally (10-40) minutes:
internal server Error 500 in the browser:

And in my vscode terminal I see:
 error [Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\felan\felan-front-app.next\server\pages_error.js'] {
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\felan\felan-front-app\.next\server\pages\_error.js'
}
[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\felan\felan-front-app.next\server\pages_error.js'] {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\felan\felan-front-app.next\server\pages\_error.js'
}

but when I rerun server (stop the local server and use npm run dev again), it works perfect until next 10-40 minutes! what should I do?
